# How to insert values that lie in the given range in to the database using sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a starting value as

```
1BC16EC001
```

and the ending value as

```
1BC16EC010
```

I want to insert the values in between (i.e 1BC16EC002,1BC16EC003 etc ) into the database automatically.

What should my query be to do this?

Comment: There are only 10 values.  Write them out individually.  That seems like the simplest solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can write the following code:

```
    BEGIN
      SET @i = 0
      WHILE @i < 10 DO
        SET @i = @i + 1
        IF @i < 10 THEN
            SET TEMP='0'+ @i
        ELSE
            SET TEMP= @i
        END IF
        INSERT INTO table VALUES('1BC16EC0'+(@TEMP)
      END WHILE
    END
```

BTW, you can change 10 to any number you want.

Comment: And yet the question is tagged [tag:mysql]

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I changed the code to MySQL. I did not notice it is MySQL